# Extracting a data with BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to loop through and download dog pictures from Unsplash. However, when I used BeautifulSoup to access the div, only some of the loops display the URL within the div class. Is there any way to get about it?

My code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os

res = requests.get('https://unsplash.com/s/photos/shiba')

doggo_soup = soup(res.text,'html.parser')

containers = doggo_soup.findAll('div',{'class','IEpfq'})

if not os.path.exists('shiba'):
    os.makedirs('shiba')

os.chdir('shiba')

index = 1

for container in containers:
    img_tag = container.img
    source = requests.get(img_tag)
    with open('shiba-'+str(index)+'jpg','wb') as output:
        output.write(source.content)
```

```
<div class="_3oSvn IEpfq" style="padding-bottom:66.6667%"><img alt="short-coated white dog on field" class="_2zEKz" data-test="photo-grid-single-col-img" style="background-color:#060606"/></div>
```

When I inspected the div class IEpfq on the developer console, all div class IEpfq contains the URL to the picture.

However when I run the code, it only showed partial information (without URL) under the same div class for 4th picture onward. (as shown in the output above) Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show an example of the partial information you're getting?

Comment: When i scrap with the script (4th container), it shows the output as below

Comment: <div class="_3oSvn IEpfq" style="padding-bottom:66.6667%"><img alt="short-coated white dog on field" class="_2zEKz" data-test="photo-grid-single-col-img" style="background-color:#060606"/></div>

Comment: However when I inspect the element, it will display the URL to the picture download

Comment: Please add that to the question body, so that the question includes all the information required to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly changed code. It downloaded 20 pictures for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os

res = requests.get('https://unsplash.com/s/photos/shiba')

doggo_soup = soup(res.text,'html.parser')

containers = doggo_soup.find_all('div',class_='_2BSIe _3pmDG')


if not os.path.exists('shiba'):
    os.makedirs('shiba', exist_ok=True)

index = 1

for container in containers:
    imgUrl = container.find('a')['href']
    source = requests.get(imgUrl)
    imageFile = open(os.path.join('shiba', os.path.basename(str(index) + '.jpg')), 'wb')
    for chunk in source.iter_content(1000000):
        imageFile.write(chunk)
    imageFile.close()
    index +=1
```

Comment: Thanks! it works for me too! May I know how do you locate the class = _2BSIe _3pmDG . I tried to find it with Inspect but with no success.

Comment: I used Isnpect tool in Chrome. Use Pick Element and point to Download photo button which is placed on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

There is several issues with your code try this it worked for me. I added exception handler, to make the process continue if any image download fails, also your code does not update the `index` counter at each iteration:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os

res = requests.get('https://unsplash.com/s/photos/shiba')

doggo_soup = soup(res.text,'html.parser')

containers = doggo_soup.findAll('div',{'class','IEpfq'})

if not os.path.exists('shiba'):
    os.makedirs('shiba')

os.chdir('shiba')

index = 1

for container in containers:
    try:
        img_tag = container.img
        source = requests.get(img_tag.get('src'))
        with open('shiba-'+str(index)+'.jpg','wb') as output:
            output.write(source.content)
        index += 1
    except:
      pass
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it works. But it only extract the first 3 pictures in the page. When I inspected the element, the URL for the 4th picture onwards can found in the developer console. However, when I run the script. It cannot detect  or retrieve the URL.